# Shouldn't it be like "as opposed to doing sth/in opposition to doing sth"?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, coordination

> Good education encourages students to think critically, as opposed to **force-feed** students.

In the example above, why does the author use "force-feed" rather than "force-feeding"?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. I understand that "doing" refers to "force-feeding", but *do* might be either the infinitive (referring to *think*) or finite present (referring to *encourages*). Could you express your question a little more clearly?

Comment: It's not clear what is troubling you. The words "do" and "doing" do not appear in your quoted sentence. If you're asking about the -*ing* be *ing*-less forms, notice that just like *doing* (as in your title), *force-feeding* is in its *-ing* form. Also, please be careful to quote verbatim (your transcription has a spelling error, and since it's a quote, we have no way of knowing whether you introduced that error, or whether it is in the original, which of course matters because it goes toward the credibility and reliability of the original quote as a whole).

Comment: Sorry.. I miswrote the OP. It was "force-feed".and the problem puzzling me is,why the OP use present simple tense rather than "ing"form

Comment: I edited my question.. check it out again ..sorry.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source, please? ... Ok, I think I found it: http://zuoye.baidu.com/question/4df6fcb8fd8e9b15ddac94f516d4fada.html , spelling-errors and all. Mystery solved: someone who is professing to teach English while simultaneously committing such heinous acts of spelling should not be trusted. In other words, consider the source. Make judgments of quality & trustworthiness. For example, here's another English leaning site which uses that sentence -- this time, correctly using the *-ing* form: http://www.italki.com/question/118351 .